# Error 400 while inserting data to elasticseach with python requests

Tags: python, post, elasticsearch

Hello I an trying to add data to my elasticsearch on my localhost. I found and example of post request:

```
data = {"key": "value", 'time_utc': time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')}
print data
r = requests.post('http://localhost:9200/macs/', json.dumps(data))
print r
```

But this give error(`<Response [400]>`
) and I am not understanding why.
Can someone help ?

Comment: no data in inserted, but when I use postman insertion works good.

Comment: 400 means a bad request, what format is the data supposed to be sent?

Comment: Normally json. It woks with postman

Answer (score 1):

```
requests.post('http://localhost:9200/macs/', data=json.dumps(data),headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.